# builde tree contructor with lodash

Tags: reactjs

Using lodash, I need to convert the following array:
Every entry of the json has : id : a unique id, parentId : the id of the parent node (which is 1 if the node is a root of the tree)

```
[{
   id: '1',
   parentId: '',
   children: [],
 }, {
   id: '2',
   parentId : '1',
   children: [],
 }, {
   id: '3',
   parentId : '2',
   children: [],
 }, {
   id: '4',
   parentId : '1',
   children: [],
 }, {
   id: '5',
   parentId : '2',
   children: [],
 }]
```

Into the following format:

```
[{
  id: '1',
  parentId : '',
  children: [{
    id: '2',
    parentId : '1',
    children: [{
        id: '3',
        parentId : '2',
        children: []
     },{
        id: '5',
        parentId : '2',
        children: [],
      }]
   }]
},{
   id: '4',
   parentId : '1',
   children: [],
}]
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You have to develop it yourself. If you have any concrete questions that arise while you develop your code, search stackoverflow for an answer, if the question has not been asked and is not covered by the documentation e.g. for [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) then the question would be suitable here.

Comment: @Martin. Thanks for your advice. I remember this

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple recursive function to achieve it.

Try like below.

```js
const array = [ { id: "1", parentId: "", children: [], }, { id: "2", parentId: "1", children: [], }, { id: "3", parentId: "2", children: [], }, { id: "4", parentId: "1", children: [], }, { id: "5", parentId: "2", children: [], }, ];

const tree = [];

const findAndAdd = (tree, node) => {
  const parent = tree.find(child => child.id === node.parentId)
  if(parent){
    parent.children.push(node)
    return true
  } else {
    tree.some(item => findAndAdd(item.children, node))
  }
  return false
}

const generateNestedTree = (array, tree) => {
  array.forEach((node) => {
    if(node.parentId === ""){
      tree.push(node)
    } else {
      findAndAdd(tree, node)
    }
  })
};

generateNestedTree(array, tree)

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```

Comment: @Hoang Le, check this out !!

Comment: Tks Amila ! It's running.

Comment: @HoangLe, note that most of the time you can process JSON without using lodash